# Haskell - deriving show for polymorphic types

Tags: haskell

First off, my background is in C++, so try not to shoot me down too hard.

In this contrived example, I'm trying to define a polymorphic type that looks like this:

```
data T x y
    = Cons1 x
    | Cons2 y
    | Neither
    deriving (Show)
```

I want a datatype that holds values of either type `x`, type `y` or neither. A variant of sorts of `Maybe a`. When I try to do this:

```
main = do
    let v = Cons1 1
    putStrLn (show v)
```

some ambiguity arises:

```
No instance for (Show y0) arising from a use of `show'
The type variable `y0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance (Show x, Show y) => Show (T x y)
    -- Defined at C:\Projects\Private\Haskell\Play\play.hs:14:27
  instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  ...plus 25 others
In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `(show t)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (show t)
In the expression:
  do { let t = Cons1 1;
       putStrLn (show t) }
```

Why is this? Why is there an ambiguity? `1` in `Cons1 1` is from what I understand a number, which all derive Show. The constructor itself, I thought, acted as a discriminator, making `Cons1 1 /= Cons2 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Cons1 1` the compiler is only able to derive the `x` type in `data T x y` and has no way to infer `y`. `x` becomes `Num a`, but what about `y`? You'll need to specify it manually in that case:

```
main = do
    let v = (Cons1 1 :: T Int Int) -- just an example
    putStrLn (show v)
```

In some cases, if you'll use explicit function types, the compiler will be able to infer it automagically. But in this case it really has no hints.

It's the same as `Nothing` being ambiguous on it's own. Is it `Maybe String`, `Maybe Int`, `Maybe Double`, ...?

Comment: If I comment out the printing line, the compiler accepts it. Is the compiler so lazy it won't even generate the show functions until I invoke show? Also, how would you model a type like this? I get the feeling that my example is bad form!

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson Weird. It should generate a "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression" compilation error. Your type is not in a bad form. `Either` is modelled pretty much the same way (two types and two type constructors for each of them).

Comment: I replaced the printed expression with an empty string, rather than deleting. Sorry about confusing the matter.